# Tabla en base a array

Tags: array, html-tabla

tengo una función que recibe un array y con los datos de dicha array debería crear una tabla mostrando los datos que contiene, pero no funciona, si alguien podría decirme cual es el error del código me seria de gran ayuda

Código:

```
function createTable(){

        let users = createUsers();

        let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        let table = document.createElement("table");

        let tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){

             let row = document.createElement("tr");

             let cellName = document.createElement("td");
             let txtCellName = document.createTextNode(users[i].name);
             cellName.appendChild(txtCellName);
             row.appendChild(cellName);

             let cellLastName = document.createElement("td");
             let txtCellLastName = document.createTextNode(users[i].lastName);
             cellLastName.appendChild(txtCellLastName);
             row.appendChild(cellLastName);

             let cellAge = document.createElement("td");
             let txtCellAge = document.createTextNode(user[i].age);
             cellAge.appendChild(txtCellAge);
             row.appendChild(cellAge);

             tblBody.appendChild(row);

        }

        table.appendChild(tblBody);
        body.appendChild(table);
        table.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás creando la tabla, pero no la estás usando.
Después de tu `for` agrega

```
table.appendChild( tblBody  );
body.appendChild( table );
```

Cuentanos como te va con esa solución

Comment: ya lo hice y sigue sin funcionar, no se que puede ser

Comment: Antes de hacer `appendChild` haz `console.log( tblBody )` y dinos que aparece

Comment: no me aparece nada

Comment: ya lo solucione, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta, puedes marcarla como correcta  permitir que otros se guíen